# Is there a way to create fake halftone holes across the entire object that doesn't completely cuts?

Tags: mesh, shaders

Basically I want to create this kind of effect in a cylinder surface, I tried doing it with cylinders + array to create multiple desired holes but does puts a lot of pressure in the program due to the mesh, that's why I'm trying to make fake holes  [image]

However, I don't want it to be completely a hole, if not to be a hole that goes inside and creates kind of a inward bump across the entire object. I recently found Voronoi but I've found all guides to be only for grayscale objects or the holes are not with bumps [image]

How can I achieve this kind of effect or which would be the tools name?

Comment: Hello, you say that you want to do it on a cylinder but you're actually showing a sphere? Also, do you want to fake the holes with a material (with a Bump node) or do you want real holes?

Comment: hey, yeah, it would be fake holes because real ones are making the program run slow and crash

Comment: Are you trying to make a trypophobia simulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the black/white factor of a *Voronoi Texture* node (randomness = 0) to control the alpha channel of a principled shader. The *Math* node, set to "greater than", controls the size of the holes:

[image]

With a *Bump* Node connected to the *Normal* input of the Principled BSDF (instead of the *Alpha* input), you can fake a displacement effect:

[image]

NOTE:
For best results, you should UV unwrap the cylinder first. For deeper holes, you will need true displacement and a higher resolution mesh, or bake normal maps...

Comment: the way I was trying used way more nodes, tysm! just wanted to know if there's a way to make the holes to not completely cut through the mesh, keeping a little bit of volume as the image (2) it doesn't needs to have a bevel

Comment: Use normal bump instead @Omaren

Comment: True. I added this in the answer.

Comment: my bad, you're right, didn't see that part, ty!  sorry for bothering, I didn't asked this but it's there a way for giving the mesh a color ramp or gradient? I did try but seems that the process changes because of the Voronoi

Comment: I think at this point you should make yourself familiar with some shader tutorials on youtube. It's definitely possible and it's not that hard to do - but it's getting a little off-topic here :-)

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification tho, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a hole, bake the normal map (or the bump map), use the normal map on your cylinder. Of course the holes can't be very deep as these are fake holes:

[image]